# What is the notion of a proof of a proposition for Martin-Löf?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-logic

The notion of *proof of a proposition* is of the most fundamental notions in Martin-Löf's work on philosophical logic, since it is conceptually prior to the notion of truth - cf "*Truth of a proposition, evidence of a judgement, validity of a proof*" (p.414). But, as far as I know, he never really gave an explicit philosophical explanation of it.

So what is a proof of a proposition for Martin-Löf? Generally speaking, we can put the question as

- What is a term of a type for Martin-Löf?

(given the Curry-Howard or proposition-as-types correspondence.)

Comment: A  proof of a proposition $A$ is a proof of the judgment "$A$ is true", which is the knowledge about this judgement.

Comment: @user40276 How can you conclude this? I can see that the a proof (or evidence) of the judgment 'A is true' is a proof of a proposition A, though.

Comment: Take a look at this paper http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~saurin/Enseignement/LMFI/articles/Martin-Lof83.pdf . I should mention too that this philosophical definition of proof leads to circularity and is not constructive (actually, not even intuitionistic), however the theory works well (just the philosophical foundations are not suited to the theory)

Comment: @user40276 Sorry, the link is broken. Do you mean *On the meanings of the logical constants and justification of the logical laws*? If so, I'm relatively familiar with it. So could you please indicate where are exactly the passages you have in mind? I would love to hear how you draw this controversial but interesting conclusion, if could (and had the time to) be more specific.

Comment: This one is not broken for now http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ulrikb/80-518-818/MartinLof83.pdf . See page 9-10 of the document (and not of the article). Special interested is in the assertions "A proof is what makes a judgement evident", "to prove = to get to know = to understand, comprehend, grasp, or see."

Comment: About the circularity, it's not a derivation of mine (a friend of mine derived this first and it's not published by the way). I may write it later when I have more time, but in essence it's about the identification of an object with the knowledge about such an object. About the failure of intuitionism, one may simply argue that $\neg \neg A$ is an evidence of $A$ from the point of view of some individual and, therefore, is a proof of $A$. The problem is that to know is not exactly the same thing as to construct, whatever these concepts may mean.

Comment: More generally, one may argue that all these problems stem from the identification of truth and provability (compare for instance with first Gödel incompleteness theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Martin-Löf has a short article on this.

*Kant and Contemporary Epistemology, Volume 54 of the series The University of Western Ontario Series in Philosophy of Science pp 87-99.
**Analytic and Synthetic Judgements in Type Theory, Per Martin-Löf***

He claims

> So the usual form of judgement, A is true, is indeed  a special case of the existential form of judgement.

He relies thus on the `intuitionist explanation of truth, [...], defined as existence of a proof, or construction, of the proposition.`

And there, he says that the synthetic forms of judgement are the existential forms of judgement.

Since I cannot copy-paste the text, I give a you a picture of the relevant pages.

[image: Analytic and Synthetic Judgements in Type Theory, Per Martin-Löf]

Another article without the machinery of the types is
**Truth and Knowability on the Principles C and K of Michael Dummett 1998**
He explicitly distinguishes between judgements, propositions, truths and proofs.

all these articles are available on

https://github.com/michaelt/michaelt.github.io/tree/master/martin-lof

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with the first paper and that truth is identified with provability for Martin-Löf. What I am interested in, though, is not judgments - but to know what exactly a "proof of a proposition" is supposed to be for him.. would you have any idea in respect to it?